# Laplace transform of $t^2 y''$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

So I need to take the Laplace transform of the following function:

$$
Eqn. 1: \\\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}{\{t^2 \ddot y\}}
$$

I've found that

$$
Eqn. 2:\\
\mathcal{L}{\{t^{n} f(t)\}} = (-1)^{n}F^{n}(s) \,\,\, \text{for}\, n\, =\, 1,\, 2,\, 3, ...
$$

So is Laplace associative? i.e.

$$
Eqn. 3:\\
\mathcal{L}{\{f_{1}(t)f_{2}(t)\}} = \mathcal{L}{\{f_{1}(t)\}} \cdot \mathcal{L}{\{f_{2}(t)\}} = F_{1}(s) \cdot F_{2}(s)
$$

or is there already a transform for the thing I'm trying to transform?

Edit: I'm transforming Eqn. 1.

Eqn 2 and 3 are the way I think I would proceed to solve the problem. Sorry, original post wasn't quite as clear as it could have been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\mathcal{L}(t f(t)) = \int_0^{\infty} t e^{-st}f(t) dt = -\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t) dt = (-1)\frac{d}{ds}F(s)
$$

so

$$
\mathcal{L}(t^n f(t)) = (-1)^n\frac{d^n}{ds^n}F(s)
$$

then

$$
\mathcal{L}(t^n f''(t)) = (-1)^n\frac{d^n}{ds^n}\left(s^2F(s)-s f'(0)-f(0)\right)
$$

Comment: awesome thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

No, just as the integral of $f(x)g(x)$ is not the product of the integrals of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

The correct form is a convoluton 
$$\mathcal{L}{\{f_{1}(t)f_{2}(t)\}} = \frac 1{2\pi i}\lim_{T \to \infty}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}F_1(\sigma)(F_2(s-\sigma)d\sigma$$

Comment: ah so Cesareo's solution isn't entirely correct then? y'' is a function of t though

Comment: It is correct, but answering the question in your title while I answered the question in the body.

Comment: ah ok I see. I meant was that thing I "found" the way to go. I'm a bit exhausted at the moment so my post isn't quite clear. But Cesareo's method is valid then for $\mathcal{L}{\{t^{2} \ddot y\}}$ thought correct? (because I totally forgot convolution :) )

Comment: Yes,.  Cesareo uses what you cite to get to the second line, then the linearity of the transform to take derivatives on both sides to get to the third.