# How do I solve with Laplace Transform $t^{2}y''-2ty'+2y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have to solve $t^{2}y''-2ty'+2y=0$ with the initial conditions $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$ using the Laplace transformation.
I only could do this

### $s^{2}\mathcal{Y}''+6s\mathcal{Y}'+6\mathcal{Y}=0$

where $\mathcal{Y}$ is the Laplace transformation of the function $y(t)$. What can I do?

Comment: **Hint:** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018721/laplace-transform-of-t2-y

Answer (score 3):

$$t^{2}y''-2ty'+2y=0$$
$$\dfrac {d^2}{ds^2}\mathcal {L} \{y''\}+2\dfrac {d}{ds}\mathcal {L} \{y'\}+2Y(s)=0$$
$$\dfrac {d^2}{ds^2} \{s^2Y(s)\}+2\dfrac {d}{ds} \{sY(s)\}+2Y(s)=0$$
$$\dfrac {d^2}{ds^2} \{s^2Y(s)\}+2sY'(s)+4Y(s)=0$$
$$s^2Y''(s)+6sY'(s)+6Y(s)=0$$
This is [Cauchy-Euler's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) .

Try $Y(s)=s^m$.

---

**Another way:**

$$s^2Y''(s)+6sY'(s)+6Y(s)=0$$
Multiply by $\mu (s)=s$
$$s^3Y''(s)+6s^2Y'(s)+6sY(s)=0$$
You can rewrite it as:
$$(s^3Y'(s))'+(3s^2Y(s))'=0$$
$$(s^3Y(s))''=0$$
Integrate twice. Apply inverse Laplace transform and initial conditions.